# Can't squash commit: it is not there

Tags: git, rebase, squash

I have a set of commits I want to squash. I know that there is one that, upon running

```
git rebase --interactive startingCommitHash
```

doesn't appear at all, so to address the problem I've decided to start squashing one by one from the tail so that when I get to the troublesome commit I can try what happens, which is quite curious. When my log shows like

squashedCommitsHash Squashing commits
troublesomeCommitHash Troublesome commit message

I run

```
git rebase --interactive HEAD~2
```

and then I get

```
pick startingCommitHash Starting commit 
pick secondHash Second commit
pick thirdHash Third commit
pick fourthHash Fourth commit 
pick fifthHash Fifth commit
pick squashedCommitsHash Squashing Travis-CI fixes
```

What?! Where's my troublesome commit? Why is it not there? And why all others have appeared, despite specifying that I only want to squash 2?

Comment: you have merge commits?

Comment: You need to rebase ONTO another commit. So grab the SHA of the commit before the startingCommitHash. e.g. git rebase -i oneBeforeStartingCommitHash

Comment: @AndrewC Now that you mention, it could very certainly be that. so I shall just ignore the fact that that ones doesn't eppear and squash the others?

Comment: @Jeff That will just show up another commit, but won't solve the problem.

Comment: For stuff like this I always find it helps to draw the part of the commit graph you're interested in.  A visualizer like `gitk` (perhaps with `--all`) can help, or `git log --graph` (with or without `--oneline` and `--all` and so on).

Comment: I can confirm it was a merge. Squashing the others worked perfectly.